# Is there a way to "verify" the performance of a video chip/driver from the command line?

Tags: performance, video

Is there a way to "verify" (or compare) the performance of a video chip/driver from the linux/unix command line?

Thanks!

:)
Asher

Answer (score 0):

Password cracking tool Hashcat can help you in this matter as it has native GPU support and hashrate is closely related with GPU performance.

It has a builtin benchmark test which can be run via `hashcat -b` and shows hashrates of different hash algorithms.

Hashrate can be considered as a measurement for performance so using those values for GPU comparison is a reliable approach in most contexts as long as the GPU driver is properly set up.